# Android : sending mms automatically

Tags: java, android, sms, mms

I have an apps that unable me to send SMS (which work pretty well so far) and i am trying to implement MMS data sending. I've looked around and so far all i could come up was this piece of code :

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.putExtra("address",personNumber);
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",shortMessage);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri3);
    sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It open the phone messaging interface and ask to send the MMS .It work well if that's what i wanted to do. But i want it to send it without asking anything from the user (my apps is something like a remote sms application) hence not really working for my case.

For good reason i know why you would need some kind of user input before sending a picture you did not take yourself, but is there any documentation about this restriction or any other way to do it ? (All information i found was from 2012, maybe there is some new info somewhere)

Thank to anyone with an answer

**EDIT :**

For anyone who want to do it, there is a way apparently. I did not have the time to do it, but here is a link on how to do it in great detail :

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2222703

It's not simple but if you don't mind using something like that, go ahead.

Comment: Take a look at SMS Popup. It's open source and it should have the code you need. https://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/

Comment: And don't count on finding newer documentation/tutorials on the subject. People only write newer documentation/tutorials when a new feature comes out, or when the apis have changed.

Comment: Looking at the SMSPopup code, it's far from being simple like i though lol, thank you for the tip though.